# Difference of meaning between gerund and participle

Tags: gerunds

What is difference of meaning between these sentences:

- Hearing the news she returned home.
- On hearing the news she returned home.

Comment: Both are fine and have the same meaning. They have a resultative interpretation equivalent to "As a result of hearing the news she returned home". Syntactically, in your second example the gerund-participial clause "hearing the news" is complement of the prep "on" ("on hearing the news is thus a PP serving as an adjunct), whereas in the first it serves directly as an adjunct.

Comment: A lot of thanks to you